# On upper central series

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and Z(G) be the center of $G$. This is the upper central series $$1=Z_{0}(G)\leq Z_{1}(G)\leq...,$$ defined by $\frac{Z_{n+1}(G)}{Z_{n}(G)}=Z\left(\frac{G}{Z_{n}(G)}\right)$.

Now prove  that $Z_{i}\left(\frac{G}{Z_{j}(G)}\right)=\frac{Z_{i+j}(G)}{Z_{J}(G)}$.

Attempt: We use of induction on $i$. It is obvious for $i=1$. Now let that we have $Z_{i}(\frac{G}{Z_{j}(G)})=\frac{Z_{i+j}(G)}{Z_{J}(G)}$, Inductive assumption. Now we have

$\frac{Z_{i+1}(\frac{G}{Z_{j}(G)})}{Z_{i}(\frac{G}{Z_{j}(G)})}=Z(\frac{\frac{G}{Z_{j}(G)}}{Z_{i}(\frac{G}{Z_{j}(G)})})=Z(\frac{\frac{G}{Z_{j}(G)}}{\frac{Z_{i+j}(G)}{Z_{J}(G)}})\cong Z(\frac{G}{Z_{i+j}(G)})=\frac{Z_{i+j+1}(G)}{Z_{i+J}(G)}\cong \frac{\frac{Z_{i+j+1}(G)}{Z_{j}(G)}}{\frac{Z_{i+J}(G)}{Z_{j}(G)}}=\frac{\frac{Z_{i+j+1}(G)}{Z_{j}(G)}}{Z_{i}(\frac{G}{Z_{j}(G)})}$. therefore $$\frac{Z_{i+1}(\frac{G}{Z_{j}(G)})}{Z_{i}(\frac{G}{Z_{j}(G)})}\cong \frac{\frac{Z_{i+j+1}(G)}{Z_{j}(G)}}{Z_{i}(\frac{G}{Z_{j}(G)})}$$. Now Do we can to say that  $Z_{i+1}(\frac{G}{Z_{j}(G)})=\frac{Z_{i+j+1}(G)}{Z_{J}(G)}$? How?

Thank you.

Comment: Use \left( , \right) so that the parentheses will automatically fit to the correct size. I did the first two cases for you.

Comment: @DonAntonio. Ok Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very perceptive of you to notice the difference between isomorphisms and equalities and how that precludes a naive application of the lattice theorem. Here's a patch for the middle:

$$\begin{array}{ccc} Z\left(\frac{G}{H}\right) & = & \frac{A}{H} \\ & \Large \Updownarrow & \\ Z\left(\frac{G/N}{H/N}\right) & = & \frac{A/N}{H/N} \end{array} $$

with $N=Z_j(G)$, $H=Z_{i+j}(G)$, and $A=Z_{i+j+1}(G)$. Hint to see why $A$ is the same in both:

$$[aH,gH]=H\iff [aN(H/N),gN(H/N)]=H/N.$$